# Including a button for a related textfield in a CQ dialog

Tags: extjs, aem

How can I include a button with an input field, so that it looks like this (without the icon):
[image]

The purpose of this is so that if somebody enters invalid text, he can click on the button for some suggestions.

(I think this part could be achieved by a JavaScript function which calls a SlingServlet, returning some suggestions to be displayed e.g. maybe as an alert.)

Comment: If you don't *specifically* want a button, you could achieve the same with a `beforesubmit` listener — clicking the overall "OK" button could call your JS function to validate the input.

Comment: this is a good idea but I need the button. I have tried the following: > <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                <myInput
                    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                    name="./myInput"
                    type="text"
                  <myButton jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget" 
     name="./myButton"   xtype="button" />
</items>    but this shows the textfield and button one bellow the other

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you've clarified in comments that having them in one line is important for you, you could wrap them both in a `toolbar` XType:

```
<toolbar
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
    xtype="toolbar">
    <items
        jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
        <input
            jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
            xtype="textfield"
            name="./myInput">
        </input>
        <button
            jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
            xtype="button"
            name="./myButton"
            text="Submit">
        </button>
    </items>
</toolbar>
```

I think you can then also style the widgets further, e.g. width of the input field.

Check out the API docs too, they have some examples of a ComboBox [on the toolbar page](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.Ext.Toolbar), which talks of type-ahead & suggested values — it sounds like it could be adapted to what you're looking for, if the `data` field came from an external JSON source (e.g. your SlingServlet), rather than coded inline.